# Group items based on timestamp

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with unique rows like this:

```
df <- unique(data.frame(Timestamp=as.POSIXct(strptime(c('2018-01-08 13:26:53', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 13:33:33', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 13:45:12', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 13:45:12', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 14:28:34', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 14:31:32',
                                                 '2018-01-08 14:31:32',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:13:16',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:25:19',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:25:19',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:25:19',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:25:19'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")),
                 Text=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C')))
```

Output:

```
             Timestamp Text
1  2018-01-08 13:26:53    A
2  2018-01-08 13:33:33    B
3  2018-01-08 13:45:12    C
4  2018-01-08 13:45:12    A
5  2018-01-08 14:28:34    B
6  2018-01-08 14:31:32    A
7  2018-01-08 14:31:32    C
8  2018-01-08 15:13:16    D
9  2018-01-08 15:25:19    A
11 2018-01-08 15:25:19    B
12 2018-01-08 15:25:19    C
```

I would like to group Items which have the same timestamp and always keep the same order of grouped items if it appeared once. So my result should look like this:

```
            Timestamp Text
1 2018-01-08 13:26:53    A
2 2018-01-08 13:33:33    B
3 2018-01-08 13:45:12    C | A
5 2018-01-08 14:28:34    B
7 2018-01-08 14:31:32    C | A
8 2018-01-08 15:13:16    D
9 2018-01-08 15:25:19    C | A | B
```

Any efficient suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `aggregate(Text~Timestamp, df, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "|"))` ?

Comment: Is there a way to have always C|A if it appeared once and not A|C?

Comment: sort it? `aggregate(Text~Timestamp, df, function(x) paste(sort(x, decreasing = T), collapse = "|"))` ?

Comment: Note that by sorting the last entry will be `C|B|A` (instead of `C|A|B`)

Comment: so do you need only `C` before `A` and rest of them would be after those two ?

Comment: Or do you actually want to keep the order of the first seen combination...?

Comment: Yes I would like to keep C|A|B in non alpabetical order because the sequence C|A appeared once.

Comment: and you can not order before the aggregation right? Because you want them in the sequence they 'came in'?

Comment: If you are talking about `C|A` being appeared at `13:45:12` then `A` appeared at first entry `13:26:53` so entry at `13:45:12` should be `A | C` by that logic. What am I missing?

Comment: @Sotos Yes I would like to keep the order they 'came in'.

Comment: @RonakShah I'm just interested in a sequence which appeared alread once not a single item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using base R

```
df <- unique(data.frame(Timestamp=as.POSIXct(strptime(c('2018-01-08 13:26:53', 
                                                        '2018-01-08 13:33:33', 
                                                        '2018-01-08 13:45:12', 
                                                        '2018-01-08 13:45:12', 
                                                        '2018-01-08 14:28:34', 
                                                        '2018-01-08 14:31:32',
                                                        '2018-01-08 14:31:32',
                                                        '2018-01-08 15:13:16',
                                                        '2018-01-08 15:25:19',
                                                        '2018-01-08 15:25:19',
                                                        '2018-01-08 15:25:19',
                                                        '2018-01-08 15:25:19'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")),
                        Text=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C')))



agg<- aggregate(df[,2], list(df[,1]), function(x) paste0(unique(x)))
```

Comment: It's a workable solution so I will accept it as an answer! Thanks to @RonakShah too!